# Модификаторы доступа - public, но только для некоторых классов

Tags: c#

Модификатор доступа "public" даёт доступ к члену класса для всех других классов. Возможно ли сделать член класса доступным только для некоторых других классов? 
Уточнения вопроса:  внутри одной сборки; следующие модификаторы доступа не подходят: public, private, internal, protected, protected internal, private protected.

Comment: Если в этой сборке есть и другие типы, которые не должны иметь доступа, то под ваши условия подходят только вложенные типы. См. мой ответ.

Comment: Если вам совсем ничего не подходит - значит у вас неправильная архитектура. Используйте вложенные типы или вообще не разделяйте тип на несколько. Либо изолируйте все эти классы в одной сборке. Опишите подробнее вашу *реальную* задачу.

Comment: Мне кажется, что этот тот самый вопрос, который с каждой правкой/уточнением обессмысливает предыдущие ответы. Автору надо было бы либо сразу чётко описать что он хочет, либо задавать разные вопросы. Не, я серьёзно: сначала пришёл Илья, дал ответ, тут же оказалась маааааленькая такая приписка, обессмыслившая его ответ, потом пришёл Андрей, дал свою версию ответа, потом опять лёгким движением руки постановка меняется... [Нехорошо](https://yandex.ru/images/search?text=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA). Убираю свой плюс с вопроса.

Comment: Извините, не получилось сразу задать правильный вопрос. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 9):

Возможность доступа из некоторых классов (не из всех):

Члены, помеченные модификатором доступа `internal` - к ним имеют доступ все типы внутри данной сборки, а также типы из *дружественных* (см. соседний ответ) сборок.

Члены, помеченные модификатором доступа `protected` - к ним имеют доступ все типы-наследники данного.

Члены, помеченные модификатором `protected internal` - это объединение двух предыдущих пунктов, т.е. имеют доступ все типы из данной и дружественных сборок, а также типы-наследники из любых сборок.

Члены, помеченные модификатором `private protected` (C# 7.2 и выше) - это пересечение первых двух пунктов, т.е. имеют доступ типы-наследники данного, но только в пределах данной сборки или дружественных.

Вложенные типы имеют неограниченный доступ ко всем членам данного типа (даже к `private`).

Answer (score 7):

Можно определить дружественные сборки пометив их специальным атрибутом

```
InternalsVisibleTo
```

Вот пример из [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/assemblies-gac/friend-assemblies):

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;  
using System;  

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("AssemblyB")]  

// The class is internal by default.  
class FriendClass  
{  
    public void Test()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Sample Class");  
    }  
}  

// Public class that has an internal method.  
public class ClassWithFriendMethod  
{  
    internal void Test()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Sample Method");  
    }  

}
```