# Разрешить одному классу менять значение в другом классе

Tags: c#, .net

Например, есть 2 класса:

```
class A{
B B;
}

class B{

 string Name;

}
```

Можно ли сделать так, что бы класс А имел полное право менять значение B, а пользователь снаружи мог только его читать?

Comment: То есть вы хотите аналог дружественного класса для C#? Прямых аналогов нет, но, возможно, Вас устроит модификатор доступа `internal`, который позволяет обращаться к члену (метод или переменная) только из той же сборки.

Comment: Да, типа дружественный класс, который имеет полный доступ к некоторому члену другого класса, однако, пользователь из вне может его только читать.

Comment: В чистом виде такого нет. Попробуйте использовать internal, а лучше, наверно, пересмотреть проект, потому что это несколько противоесстественно)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774073/218063

Answer (score 5):

Да, такое есть. Подобной функциональностью обладают внутренние классы. Вот вам пример:

```
public class Test
{
    public int X { get; private set; }

    public class TestMutator
    {
        public static void Mutate(Test t) { t.X++; }
    }
}
```

```
Test test = new Test();
Console.WriteLine(test.X); // 0
Test.TestMutator.Mutate(test);
Console.WriteLine(test.X); // 1
```

Этой возможностью часто пользуются, например, для реализации шаблона «Итератор». Например, [энумератор `List<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,1140) в Майкрософтовской реализации определён внутри, и имеет доступ к закрытому полю `_version`.

Для внешних классов подобной функциональности нет, т. к. доступ к «внутренностям» класса — нарушение инкапсуляции.

Comment: Вроде, то что нужно, но не нравится, что к внутреннему классу нужно обращаться через точку, что делаем имена длинными.=(

Comment: @User100500: Ну так используйте `var`, делов-то! А экземпляр внутреннего класса пусть создаёт внешний класс, например.