# Вызвать необобщенную функцию обобщенного класса

Tags: c#, generics

Допустим, есть класс `MyClass<T>`. В этом классе есть метод `Common()`.

В переменной `container` типа `object` у меня могут хранится, к примеру, объекты типов `MyClass<string>`, `MyClass<int>` и `MyClass<bool>`.

Я хочу иметь доступ к функции `Common` в любом случае, но для этого мне надо привести объект к конкретному типу.

Я могу создать интерфейс, предоставляющий доступ к этому методу, но можно ли в таком случае как то сразу привести тип к общему шаблону ака "`(MyClass<>)container`"?

Просто у меня от `MyClass<T>` в будущем будет еще несколько дочерних обобщенных классов и для каждого так же писать новый интерфейс ради пары новых методов не очень удобно.

P.S. Ну еще можно вызвать метод через рефлексию, но это тоже такое себе решение...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придется заводить базовый класс или интерфейс с методом `Common()`. Дело в том, что классы `MyClass<string>` и `MyClass<int>` не являются потомками/предками друг друга и у них нет никакого общего предка кроме `object`. Тут есть преимущество (ООП ради этого, собственно, и существует) — вам не потребуется приведение типов, `container` будет типизирован и вы сможете вызывать нужный метод прямо у него.

```
public interface ICommonable
{
    void Common();
}

public class MyClass<T> : ICommonable
{
    public void Common()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Если вы не хотите заводить интерфейс из-за того, что его может реализовать какой-то сторонний класс, вы можете поступить следующим образом:

```
public abstract class Commonable
{
    internal Commonable() { }
    public abstract void Common();
}

public sealed class MyClass<T> : Commonable
{
    public override void Common()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

(см. [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774087/218063) ответ про модификаторы доступа), т. е. после того, как вы предоставите сборку с этими классами клиенту, он сможет создавать только экземпляры `MyClass<T>`, но не сможет создать другой класс, реализующий `Commonable`.

Варианты решения с использованием рефлексии или DRL тут я не рассматриваю, т. к. это уже не настоящее ООП и статическая типизация и к ним следует прибегать только в крайнем случае, когда других решений не существует (+ они несут дополнительные накладные расходы).

*в будущем будет еще несколько дочерних обобщенных классов и для каждого так же писать новый интерфейс ради пары новых методов не очень удобно.* — добро пожаловать в реальный мир, который не совсем похож на картинку с рекламного буклета :)

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.